# Android studio multi module project launches module instead of main app

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a multi module project

It has a main app, several libraries, and those `libraries have "demo" activities`

When I run my run configuration, it installs 4 apps on my device, and runs one of the demo activities instead of my main app

If i `uninstall my main app` - the other 3 apps that are installed with it also get uninstalled
all 4 apps are named exactly the same (?) with the same icon, and only clicking one of them actually launches the app

How do I fix this situation ?